# SQL Combine similar tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure if it is just a Monday brain fart, but I can't figure out how to combine these two tables.

Table 1

```
Year    Month          EMS
2014    October         1
2015    January         6
2015    February        1
2015    April           4
```

Table 2

```
Year    Month          TaRR
2015    January         28
2015    February        6
2015    March           7
2015    April           5
```

Final Table

```
Year    Month           TaRR    EMS
2014    October          0       1
2015    January          28      6
2015    February         6       1
2015    March            7       0
2015    April            5       4
```

As you can see both tables have year and month, though one table or the other might be missing a month for a year, like how table 2 doesnt have october 2014.  How can I accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

You want a `FULL JOIN`. A full join is kinda like a left and right join at the same time, so records for both tables will be displayed even if no matching record exists on the other table.

```
SELECT
    Year = ISNULL(T.Year, N.Year),
    Month = ISNULL(T.Month, N.Month),
    TaRR = N.TaRR,
    EMS = T.EMS
FROM
    Table1 AS T
    FULL JOIN Table2 AS N ON
        T.Year = N.Year AND
        T.Month = N.Month
```

As records from any of both tables might be null, you might want to set default values for them.

Comment: you might want to handle the null case for the 2 data values as well...

Comment: Awesome, let me give it a try.  Thank you so much for the quick response.  Monday, ughhh